# Encrypt on Windows Phone 8.1 in C# and decrypt in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, windows-phone-8.1

The C# is on the client end while Java code is used in a service. Windows phone encrypts the data while Java decrypts the data using the same symmetric key.

**Below is my C# method for encryption**

```cs
public static string EncryptAesTest(string data, string password)
{
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
    CryptographicKey AES;
    HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha512);
    Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

    string encrypted;

    try
    {

        byte[] hash = new byte[16];
        Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Convert.FromBase64String(password)));
        byte[] temp;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
        AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));
        IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null));
        return encrypted;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "encryption error";
    }
}
```

**Below is my Java class for decryption**

```java
private SecretKeySpec secretKey;
public void setKey() {
    skey = "mykey";
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = skey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        logger.debug("Key length ====> " + key.length);
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
        setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64
                .decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: And does it work? If not, do you get any errors?

Comment: Do not use ECB if your encrypting more than 1 block.

Comment: One uses pkcs5, the other pkcs7

Comment: Looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733424/how-use-aes-ecb-pkcs7padding-algorithm-in-windows-phone-7/11738873#11738873) question (windows phone 7 - AES)

Comment: Why did you create a new account? You could have used your old one. Since you've asked another question, you can delete the [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824728/i-need-a-java-equivalent-of-my-c-sharp-aes-encryption) (using your other account). See also: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @AlexK. PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding is the [same thing](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/13022).

Answer (score 0):

The key generation is not complete. For some reason, your C# code uses sets the last byte of the key to the same value as the first byte with the following code:

```
Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
```

(To my understanding, this could should throw some exception, because you can't copy 16 bytes into the 16 byte array `hash` if you begin at index 15.)

You could do the same (bad) thing in Java

```
public void setKey() {
    skey = "mykey";
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = skey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        logger.debug("Key length ====> " + key.length);
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
        key[15] = key[0]; // added

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

**Things to consider:**

- **ECB** mode does not provide semantic security and **it should never be used**. Use at the very least CBC mode with a random IV for each encryption under the same key.
- **Passwords should be hashed multiple times.** A single hash makes it easy for an attacker to brute-force the password, because this is operation is fast. You should use Password-based Encryption with a strong key derivation function like PBKDF2 (more than 100,000 iterations), scrypt or bcrypt. Don't forget to use a random salt.
- **Authenticate your ciphertexts.** You would want to detect (malicious) manipulations of your ciphertexts in transit. This can be done either with an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or with an encrypt-then-MAC scheme by running a MAC algorithm over your ciphertexts. A strong MAC is HMAC-SHA256.